# con.open has an error.I have a connection error an my code looks like this

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
 if (lblevent.Text == Request.QueryString["name"])
 {  
      string EventName = Request.QueryString["name"];
      const string SQL = "SELECT SMS FROM Event WHERE EventName = @EventName";

      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
      using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
           Command.Parameters.Add("@EventName", EventName);                      
           {
                con.Open();//at here the "con" has an error it says:"'con' does not exist on current context."
           }
 }
```

Actually i have already declared an sqlconnection(con) int he above code but it does not read it. Please someone help.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
 Command.Parameters.Add("@EventName", EventName);
{
    con.Open();
    ...
}
```

That's equivalent to:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
    {
        Command.Parameters.Add("@EventName", EventName);
    }
}
{
    con.Open();
    ...
}
```

At that point I hope it's obvious what's wrong - when you call `con.Open` you're no longer within the `using` statement body. You want:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
{
    Command.Parameters.Add("@EventName", EventName);                      
    con.Open();
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am still learning. So sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add brackets.

```
if (lblevent.Text == Request.QueryString["name"])
            {  
       string EventName = Request.QueryString["name"];
                const string SQL = "SELECT SMS FROM Event WHERE EventName = @EventName";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
                  {
                   using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
                     {
                      Command.Parameters.Add("@EventName", EventName);                      
                      con.Open();//at here the "con" has an error it says:"'con' does not exist on current context."
                     }
                  }
             }
```